# Python built in filtering of list not returning None item

Tags: python, function, filter

When I try to filter a list, I lose the type None item in the output. My code is below:

```
def filter_compute(my_list):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x>5 if type(x)==int else x, map_compute(my_list)))

filter_compute(['cup', '321', 2, ['x'], 4])
```

The output from map_compute should be as follows:

```
map_compute(['cup', '321', 2, ['x'], 4])
output ['puc', '123', 4, None, 16]
```

So the iterable into the filter function from map_compute should be: ['puc', '123', 4, None, 16]

The output I expect is: ['puc', '123', None, 16]

But the output I'm getting is: ['puc', '123', 16]

For some reason the None item does not get outputted.

Comment: Try `list(filter(lambda x: x>5 if isinstance(x, int) else True, map_compute(my_list)))`

Comment: How are we supposed to verify what `map_compute` produces when you didn't share the code for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter` takes a predicate, i.e. a function that returns a boolean, and an iterable. Your predicate, `lambda x: x>5 if type(x)==int else x`, returns `True` if the element is an integer that is larger than 5, `False` if it is an integer less than or equal to 5, and *the element itself otherwise*.

When the element is `None`, `filter` therefore tests for the truthiness of `None`, which evaluates to `False`, therefore it is filtered out.

If you want to *only* filter out integers <= 5, return True in the case that the element is a different type:

```
def filter_compute(my_list):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x>5 if isinstance(x, int) else True, map_compute(my_list)))

filter_compute(['cup', '321', 2, ['x'], 4])
```

---

In general, many people find `filter` a bit confusing and prefer a list comprehension:

```
def filter_compute(my_list):
    return [x for x in my_list if not (isinstance(x, int) and x <= 5)]
```

Comment: SOLVED! Thanks so much! Your explanation is easy to follow as well.